# Difference between search.maven.org and mvnrepository.com

Tags: maven

What's the difference between https://search.maven.org/ and https://mvnrepository.com/?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`search.maven.org` is the [official central search engine](https://search.maven.org) of Central Repository handled and very well maintained by

- [Sonatype Inc.](https://www.sonatype.com/)
- with support etc. https://central.sonatype.org/
- Status Information about Central: https://status.maven.org/

Whereas the part https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ is the real Central repository (distributed world wide via CDN) which is being used by default by [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), Gradle etc.

`mvnrepository.com` is a *search engine* (not always up to date) and sometimes misused as a repository, which does not work because it's only a *search engine*. The site says it is maintained by Twitter user [@frodriguez](https://twitter.com/frodriguez) whose profile identifies them as Fernando Rodriguez Olivera.

Comment: does that mean better stick to the  https://search.maven.org/  and  https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ right?

Comment: Right @zyxue that's the recommended way.

Comment: If it's official, it would really be helpful to mention it somewhere in maven's official documentation. I just spent dozens of minutes searching. Thanks anyway!

Comment: mvnrepository.com used to be better than search.maven.org in terms of usability but it seems like search.maven.org has improved a bit over the past few years.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62882748/1858327) is very in-depth and likely to answer all of your questions. It is true that `search.maven.org` is the official search engine.

One thing that `mvnrepository.com` still does better (because `search.maven.org` does not do it at all) is tell you what libraries are popular. For example, see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/popular) that JUnit is the most popular with over 121,000 uses! This can be a useful feature for developers who are hesitant to add dependencies to their projects because they don't want their consumers to have to pull in yet another dependency.

For example, if you were considering pulling in `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3` then you may feel better knowing that it is the 6th most popular library overall (and 2nd most popular ["core utility"](https://mvnrepository.com/open-source/core-utilities)). It is more likely that your consumers are using this library already than something else.

Of course that's not the most scientific thing but it's still a cool feature that is unique to it.

Comment: BTW: A hint about your link to most popular (junit) which references to out dated JUnit 4 and Junit 3... which also has the last release in 2021... I would never recommend to start a project today with JUnit 4... Start with JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5)... it shows from my understanding only the usage of other artifacts in repos (referenced in other pom files) but **not** the overall usage of JUnit 4 or alike (in number of downloads from central or other repos)...121,000 uses is the total over all version which includes vulnerable versions etc...

Comment: Very important for example https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin shows used by 141 artifacts (which is in general an issue; a plugin as a dependency is wrong!). The number of downloads on central for maven-compiler-plugin counts ca. 22,5 million times (for all different versions) only in january 2023.. (https://twitter.com/khmarbaise/status/1628872566147280899?s=20)