# What is official search engine for Maven Central?

Tags: maven, sonatype, central

I believe search.maven.org used to be de-facto solution for searching maven central.

Also people [claim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62882189/difference-between-search-maven-org-and-mvnrepository-com/62882748#62882748) [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430423/recommendable-maven-repository-search-engines/7100218#7100218) to official search engine.

If it is official, why it is now redirecting to central.sonatype.com?

Is it ethical to do so?

Has Apache anything to do with this transition?

Answer (score 0):

Because MavenCentral belongs to Sonatype.

Simple as that.